# XSLT. How to choose needed tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

[image: <i>]

How to choose "red rectangle" from another TD tag ?

SOURCE of xml. How to correctly choose `<TD valign="top" width="40%">`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TD width="10">
<IMG alt="" height="1" src="images/avro/spacer.gif" width="10"/>
</TD>
<TD valign="top" width="40%">
<B>Outward:</B>
<STRONG>Tue 18 December 2007</STRONG>
<BR/>
<BR/>
<B>12:00</B>
Depart Malaga, Costa del Sol (AGP)
<BR/>
<BR/>
<B>13:40</B>
Arrive London Luton (LTN)
<BR/>
<BR/>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">...</SCRIPT>
<BR/>
<BR/>
<B>Monarch Scheduled ZB13</B>
<BR/>
Total flight time: 0240
</TD>
```

This variant doesn't work

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Airlanes</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
      </tr>
       <xsl:for-each select="//TD[@valign='top' and @width='40%']">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="STRONG" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuLep.png)

Comment: Please post your code as code, not as a picture. Also, the question can be read in a number of ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to choose "red rectangle" from another TD tag ?

This is a trick question, not an easy one. Assuming the "another TD tag" is a **sibling** of the TD element you want, you could *probably* use this XPath expression:

```
../TD[@valign='top' and @width='40%']
```

to select it.

I say "probably" because this will select **all** TD elements that are siblings of the context node and satisfy the conditions in the predicate.

---

### Added:

Your XSLT does **not** "*choose from another TD tag*". Your context node is the `/` root node - and from there the instruction:

```
<xsl:for-each select="TD[@valign='top' and @width='40%']">
```

selects nothing, because `TD` is not a child of of the current node. You should try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//TD[@valign='top' and @width='40%']">
```

This is a speculation because you have still not shown us your input nor the expected output.

Comment: `<xsl:for-each select="TD[@valign='top' and @width='45%']">
      <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="STRONG" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>` This variant doesn't work

Comment: **1.** The `../` part is significant -- **2.** Don't expect us to troubleshoot your code when it's taken out of context - see [mcve].

Comment: I posted all my XSLT. If I delete  `<TD width="10">
<IMG alt="" height="1" src="images/avro/spacer.gif" width="10"/>
</TD>` from source, code will be work.

Comment: See the addition to my post.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I just needed to add root.